# how to build a custom control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I want to build a server control. Which contain child custom control.

```
<MyParentControl>
    <MyChildControl>
    </MyChildControl>
</MyParentControl>
```

I don't know it How to build. So, help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit of googling should do the trick for you - anyway, for starters, here are a couple of links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea.aspx

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Custom-Server-Controls.aspx (see Composite server controls heading)

**Edit**: Oh! I see that you want to have template based controls - see below good article that should start to you on the same:

[Building Templated Custom ASP.NET Server Controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx)

Comment: +1 Wanted to provide the same answer when I saw this question in the list.